# Spring Batch DB2 update DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON fails

Tags: spring, db2, spring-batch, spatial

I am trying to insert a polygon into db2 table hosted on z/OS
This is my database Item Writer

```
<bean id="databaseItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>  
        <![CDATA[         
          INSERT INTO SAMPLE_GEOMETRIES
                    (GEO_NAME, GEOMETRY)
            VALUES
                    ( ?, DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON(?, 1))
         ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.amex.elbs.DAO.GeometriesItemPreparedStatementSetter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my custom prepared statement setter

public class GeometriesItemPreparedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter{

```
@Override
public void setValues(Geometries item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString(1, item.Id);
    ps.setString(2, item.Polygon);
}
```

}

This is my sample input file. It is pipe delimited and it has the ID and the Polygon Co-ordinates.

```
pm251|'POLYGON((-159.335174733889 21.9483433404175,-159.327130348878 22.0446395507162,-159.295025589769 22.1248124949548,-159.343195828355 22.1970166285359,-159.391366885913 22.2291198667724,-159.576012589057 22.2131796383001,-159.712505933171 22.1490592515515,-159.800814224332 22.0366665967853,-159.736592652746 21.9644203111023,-159.640246973766 21.9483657695954,-159.576021285803 21.8841361312636,-159.439545188912 21.8680716835921,-159.335174733889 21.9483433404175))', 1
```

The below statement when executed on z/OS is successful.

```
 ,INSERT,INTO SAMPLE_GEOMETRIES
  (GEO_NAME, GEOMETRY)
  VALUES
  ( 'PM',
  DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON('POLYGON((
       -159.335174733889 21.9483433404175,
       -159.327130348878 22.0446395507162,
       -159.295025589769 22.1248124949548,
       -159.343195828355 22.1970166285359,
       -159.391366885913 22.2291198667724,
       -159.576012589057 22.2131796383001,
       -159.712505933171 22.1490592515515,
       -159.800814224332 22.0366665967853,
       -159.736592652746 21.9644203111023,
       -159.640246973766 21.9483657695954,
       -159.576021285803 21.8841361312636,
       -159.439545188912 21.8680716835921,
       -159.335174733889 21.9483433404175))',1))
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
DSNE615I NUMBER OF ROWS AFFECTED IS 1
```

This is what I get when I execute

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-245, SQLSTATE=428F5, SQLERRMC=DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON, DRIVER=4.12.55
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.c(mn.java:2621)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.d(mn.java:2609)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.a(mn.java:2085)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.nn.a(nn.java:7054)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.a(mn.java:2062)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.ib(mn.java:2055)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.nn.rc(nn.java:3219)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.nn.s(nn.java:3370)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.nn.l(nn.java:2499)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.nn.addBatch(nn.java:2438)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Are you saying you were successful with SPUFI (or something else, if so what?) to test the SQL? And then it failed trying to execute it from a program? Have you checked the message/code, https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n245.dita, and can you make anything of that?

Comment: I'll try removing '' quote; `ps.setString()` should do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

The [error message for SQLCODE -245](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n245.dita?lang=en) reads: "THE INVOCATION OF FUNCTION routine-name IS AMBIGUOUS".

Apparently, there are more than one version of `DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON` in the database, accepting different types of arguments. You are using an untyped parameter marker: `DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON(?, 1)`, so DB2 is unable to determine which version of `DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON` you want.

Add an explicit cast to the function invokation using the appropriate data type, for example:

```
DB2GSE.ST_POLYGON(CAST( ? AS VARCHAR(1000)), 1)
```

Comment: Now I am getting a different error. Error from Spring Batch - Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.12.55] Batch failure ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null. There is 1 error I see on DB2 Logs but I am not sure if it is related to this - Error from DB2 Logs - "SQLCODE = -254, ERROR:  A NON-ATOMIC INSERT STATEMENT ATTEMPTED
TO PROCESS MULTIPLE ROWS OF DATA, BUT ERRORS OCCURRED".

Comment: I wrote another stored procedure to do this same update and I was getting this SQLCODE = -245 for that one too.. Now when I added the CAST, the SP worked. So I think this new error is something from Spring Batch